# Mice: Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:1:448: unexpected ')' in

Tags: r, error-handling, r-mice

When I test a model for multilevel imputation with mice, I get an error message that I do not understand.
This is my code:

```
CoreMulti <- subset(Short, select = c(CHILDID,                                                                                                     
                                     s_id_K,                                                                                                    
                                     X12SESL,homelangK, T2ENNAT,                                                                            
                                     X_RACETH_R, X_CHSEX_R, X1KAGE_R, X1PLTOT, X1EBRSTOT, X1NRWABL,                                         
                                     X1MTHETK5, X1RTHETK5, X1DCCSTOT,                                                                                
                                     T4RLVINF, T4INTSTY, T4REGVWL, T4IRGVWL, T4RD1IND, T4RD1FLN, T4CMPSES, T4CONPRN, T4WRTSKIL,
                                     T4PLCVL, T4WHNUM, T4COINS, T4GRPHAC, T4ESTQNT, T4MEASU, T4STRAT, T4FRACTN,
                                     T4OBSERV, T4EXPLAN, T4CLSSF, T4SCIPRT, T4CMSCIN, T4PHYSCN, T4LIFSCN, T4ERSPSN,                                                 
                                     X6RTHETK5, X6MTHETK5, X6STHETK5                                                                                 
                                     ))

pred2 <- make.predictorMatrix(CoreMulti)

#Cluster Variable for multilevel imputation
pred2[,"s_id_K"] <- -2

#Variables not imputed,
pred2["CHILDID",] <- 0
pred2["s_id_K",]  <- 0

#Variables not predicting
pred2[,"CHILDID"] <- 0
pred2[,"s_id_K"]  <- 0

pred2

#Change Method
meth2 <- make.method(CoreMulti)
meth2[] <- "2l.pmm"
meth2

#Level 1 Factors: 2l.binary
meth2["homelangK"]  <-"2l.binary"
meth2["T2ENNAT"]    <-"2l.binary"
meth2["X_CHSEX_R"]  <-"2l.binary"

meth2["CHILDID"] <- ""
meth2["s_id_K"] <- ""

imp4 <- mice(CoreMulti, m=1, method=meth2, predictorMatrix=pred2, maxit=1, seed=123)
```

This is the error message:

> Error in str2lang(x) : :1:448: unexpected ')'
> 1: T+T4RLVINF+T4INTSTY+T4REGVWL+T4IRGVWL+T4RD1IND+T4RD1FLN+T4CMPSES+T4CONPRN+T4WRTSKIL+T4PLCVL+T4WHNUM+T4COINS+T4GRPHAC+T4ESTQNT+T4MEASU+T4STRAT+T4FRACTN+T4OBSERV+T4EXPLAN+T4CLSSF+T4SCIPRT+T4CMSC

I do not know why this error occurs. When I run a single-level imputation everything was fine. Is there something problematic with the names of my variables?

Comment: Can you make your post reproducible and provide `dput(Short)`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example